_sp_id is regenerating everytime a user logs out
Everytime a user log out from the reactJS site the _sp_id in cookies and the domain user id in snowplow is changing ,i even checked the code but everything looks good but i'm not getting why it's getting changed everytime?
Did anyone came across of the same problem ?
Any available info on the problem is much appreciated.
Thank you.
